# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adapter', 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, kivy

This is a 3 questions in 1.

Error #1: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Error #2: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adapter'

I have been trying to debug this for hours

1. When i click the Add button, i get Error #1
2. When i click the Delete button i get Error #2
3. How to style Kivy ListItemButton and Spinner. I've read the documentation but couldn't understand!

I am sorry if my questions offends you.

here is the github repository: https://github.com/CoreElites/nairamanager

Thank you

here is the kivy file: nairamanager.kv

```
<ViewEditProducts>:

BoxLayout:
    product_name: product_name
    product_list: product_list
    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: (1,None)
        height: root.height*.1
        BackButton:
            id: back_button
            markup: True
            align: "center"
            font_size: "50sp"
            size_hint: (.1,1)
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = "news_feed_screen"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        TopLabel:
            text: "[b]View Edit Products[/b]"
            halign: "left"
            markup: True
            font_size: "15sp"
            font_name: "Arimo"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: (1,None)
        height: (root.height*.07)+self.padding[1]+self.padding[3]
        spacing: 10
        padding: (root.width*.25,root.height*.1,root.width*.25,root.height*.03)
        UniTextInput:
            id: product_name
            hint_text: "Product Name"
        GreenButton:
            text: "Add"
            size_hint: (.3,1)
            on_press: root.add_product()
        GreenButton:
            id: delete_green_button
            text: "Delete"
            size_hint: (.3,1)
            on_press: root.delete_product()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (1,root.height*.3)
        padding: (root.width*.25,0,root.width*.25,root.height*.1)
        ListView:
            id: product_list
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[str(i) for i in range(1,32)], selection_mode="multiple", cls=ListItemButton)
```

This is the actual code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# import kivy configuration file
from kivy.config import Config
# Config.set("graphics", "resizable", 0)

import kivy

# kivy version in use
kivy.require("1.9.1")

# importing needed classes
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.window import WindowBase
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty,ListProperty,StringProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import                ScreenManager,Screen,FadeTransition,FallOutTransition,WipeTransition,NoTransition,SlideTransition,RiseInTransition,SwapTransition

# Change the background color of window
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)


class LoginSignUp(Screen):
    pass

class Login(Screen):
    pass

class SignUp(Screen):
    pass

class SignUpTerms(Screen):
    pass

class NewsFeed(Screen):
    pass

class ViewEditProfile(Screen):
    pass

class ViewEditProducts(Screen):
    product_name = ObjectProperty()
    product_list = ObjectProperty()

    def add_product(self):
        # Get product name
        product_name = self.product_name.text

        # Add to list
        self.product_list.data.extend([product_name])

        # Refresh list
        self.product_list._trigger_reset_populate()

    def delete_product(self,*args):

        # If item selected
        if self.product_list.adapter.selection:

            # Get the text from selected
            selection = self.product_list.adapter.selection[0].text

            # Remove the item
            self.product_list.remove(selection)

            # Refresh list
            self.product_list._trigger_reset_populate()

class ProductList(ListItemButton):
    pass


class ViewEditExpenditures(Screen):
    pass

class ViewEditAssetsLiabilities(Screen):
    pass

class GetLoan(Screen):
    pass

class FinancialStatement(Screen):
    pass

class ProfitLossStatement(Screen):
    pass

class BalanceSheet(Screen):
    pass

class SalesForecast(Screen):
    pass

class About(Screen):
    pass

# Screen management
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):

    # Set property for screens
    transition = NoTransition()
    login_signup = ObjectProperty(None)
    login = ObjectProperty(None)
    signup = ObjectProperty(None)
    signup_terms = ObjectProperty(None)
    view_edit_profile = ObjectProperty(None)
    view_edit_products = ObjectProperty(None)
    view_edit_expenditures = ObjectProperty(None)
    view_edit_assets_liabilities = ObjectProperty(None)
    get_loan = ObjectProperty(None)
    financial_statement = ObjectProperty(None)
    profit_loss_statement = ObjectProperty(None)
    balance_sheet = ObjectProperty(None)
    sales_forecast = ObjectProperty(None)
    news_feed = ObjectProperty(None)
    about = ObjectProperty(None)

class NairaManagerRegister(Screen):
    pass


class NairaManagerApp(App):
    icon = "images/favicon_32.png"
    title = "Naira Manager"

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="Roboto",     fn_regular="fonts/roboto_regular.ttf", fn_bold="fonts/roboto_bold.ttf")
    LabelBase.register(name="Arimo", fn_regular="fonts/arimo_regular.ttf", fn_bold="fonts/arimo_bold.ttf")
    LabelBase.register(name="Webdings", fn_regular="fonts/webdings.ttf")
    NairaManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your Q and relevant snippet of your code rather than simply post a link. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Again please edit with a [mcve] of the code, not point us at a link

Comment: Tried doing that, it didn't work. Telling me my code not indented properly when it is.

Comment: `self.product_name.text ... product_cost_price.text ... product_selling_price.text` I'd guess one of those are `None`, then `if self.product_list.adapter.selection:` would likely be that `.adapter` there is `None`

Comment: to insert a code block in SO you need to paste it in the select and hit the `{}` button to format it into a code block (indents it by an extra 4 spaces)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, i don't get you.

Comment: you are trying to access a `.text` attribute and getting an error saying `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` so then one of `self.product_name` or `product_cost_price` or `product_selling_price` must be `None`

Comment: Okay, got it. How do i fix it? @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: maybe figure out why it is `None` instead of something with a `.text` attribute would be a good place to start, i don't know enough about kivy to give you any specific pointers. good luck though.

Comment: Thank you @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Answer (score -1):

It is very late now, but I had a similar problem. This code can be made to work by putting this code `product_name: product_name
product_list: product_list` outside the `BoxLayout:`. I think problem is due to scope of `product_list`.